# Auto Scrolling in Data gridview that is C# window application

Tags: gridview

I have a question i want  to make auto scrollable data gridview in which whole grid get popup with data from database as soon as form load but it show 20 records only in one go which means as soon as as page load it show first 20 record then it  we use timer and in 5 min next 20 record show and so on and as soon as it reaches last it will start from starting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
 //Global Variable Declaration 

 int TotalRow, Temp_TotalRow;
 int Displayrow = 20;

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval = 5000;
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    TotalRow = dataGridView1.RowCount;
    Temp_TotalRow = TotalRow; 
}    

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
    if (TotalRow <= Displayrow)
    {

        TotalRow = dataGridView1.RowCount;
        dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex += Displayrow;
        TotalRow = Temp_TotalRow - dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
    }

 }
```